# Building Boost 1.55 for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, boost, boost-build

While building `Boost 1.55` for `vs2013` (`vc120`) my serialization library was skipped due to following error:

> ../transform_width.hpp(151) : error C3861: 'min': indentifier not found

I solved this by including the algorithm header in `transform_width.hpp`:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

I figured that was the issue because std::min is used at line 151:

```
unsigned int i = std::min(missing_bits, m_remaining_bits);
```

Is this a known issue? 
Is there another solution to this issue (one that doesn't require changes in boost)?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html

Comment: It seems to be a known issue; there's several tickets filed: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9421 https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9196 and there's also a patch available: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8757 so I guess the next version will include the fix.